# Open "Site settings" from html/javascript PWA

Tags: android, permissions, notifications, progressive-web-apps

is it possible to open the site settings (where the user can accept or block Permissions) from javascript or html (using a specific URI scheme for example) from a PWA? I am interested for now on Android, but of course this would be very useful on any OS.

The main issue is that in PWA it is very difficult for some users (sometimes impossible) to view or activate permissions for Notifications (if blocked from before), even though you display messages or you offer them documentation that show how you do it.

For example you can open this in Chrome (the url bar lock icon or long press on PWA icon):

[image: android site setting screenshot]